# How do I return the text of a WebElement using Perl's Selenium::Remote::Driver?

Tags: perl, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I feel like I must be missing something obvious.  I know the XPath to a WebElement and I want to compare the text in that element to some string.

Say the XPath for the element is `/html/body/div/a/strong` and I want to compare it to `$str`.

So it shows up in source like `...<strong>find this string</strong>`

So I say

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;

# Fire up a Selenium object, get to the page, etc..

Test::More::ok($sel->find_element("/html/body/div/a") eq $str, "Text matched");
```

When I run this the test fails when it should pass.  When I try to print the value of `find_element($xpath)` I get some hash reference.  I've googled around some and find examples telling me to try `find_element($xpath)->get_text()` but `get_text()` isn't even a method in the original package.  Is it an obsolete method that used to actually work?

Most of the examples online for this module say "It's easy!" then show me how to `get_title()` but not how to check the text at an XPath.  I might be going crazy.

Comment: Selenium::Remote::WebDriver definitely has a method named `find_element()`, and Selenium::Remote::WebElement definitely has a method named `get_text()`. Have you tried using them? Did they work?

Comment: Ah!  I didn't even look in WebElement for `get_text()`.  That must be it.  Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha. `$sel->find_element(...)->get_text()` works fine on my end, though it looks like it'll error out if the element isn't found.

Comment: So I guess a bigger question is do I need to create a new WebElement instance for the element in question on this page just to get at that method?  Or is that nested somewhere in my Driver instance?

Comment: `find_element()` should return a WebElement for you to use. (You probably *could* make one, but ew. :p )

Comment: It worked!  Passed test!  Thanks again!

Comment: Hey @rutter, if you want to post your solution as an answer I'll gladly accept it.  :)

Comment: Sure, just did. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on our comment thread, I'm posting this as an answer:

Selenium::Remote::WebDriver definitely has a method named `find_element()`, and Selenium::Remote::WebElement definitely has a method named `get_text()`.

Something like this...

```
my $text = $sel->find_element(...)->get_text();
```

...works fine on my end, though it looks like it'll error out if the element isn't found.